# Need help parsing out a file into two key fields per line

Tags: java

I am trying to write a Java method that will parse out a text file one line at a time. In the following example I want to take the number at the front of the line and use that as one key value and the the FFM number as the next key field up until the alpha numeric characters which in the following cases is CH which is not part of the key sequence.

```
  107458982                                                       FFM00000000000713432CH
```

Once the keys are separated then I want to take them and make one key field.

so in the end each line will have a key field that is actually 19 bytes long. This is what the key field looks like at the end of each line. I want to push these key fields on to an ArrayList so that I can compare them to another txt file that has similar type structures. I thought that this would be easy but it is turning out a lot harder than I thought that it might be.

```
    Key Filed --> 107458982FFM00000000000713432
```

My text file, in this case, has a blank line on every other line so I need to just skip a blank line which is not in my code below.

**Question: How would I parse this file out as simple and quickly as possible into my key fields which will make my single key?**

Code:

```
private ArrayList<String> scannerRead4(String inFileUsed) {
        ArrayList<String> tempList = null;
        try {
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inFileUsed));
            try {
                String line;
                while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    String[] s = line.split(" ");

                    for (int index=0;index<line.length()-1; index++) {
                        System.out.println("s: " + s[index]);
                    }
                    //tempList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(line.split(" ")));
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return tempList;
    }
```

File context that needs to be parsed

```
107458982                                                       FFM00000000000713432CH
107462291                                                       FFM00000000001835472T                              

107462291                                                       FFM00000000002200570T                              

107462291                                                       FFM00000000002432274T                              

108018296                                                       FFM00000000001431509T                              

108018296                                                       FFM00000000001553064T                              

108122386                                                       FFM00000000001211063T                              


108122386                                                       FFM00000000001862517T                              


108491927                                                       FFM00000000004556330T                              


108500569                                                       FFM00000000001682124                               


108500569                                                       FFM00000000002023040                               


108523927                                                       FFM00000000000611642                               


108523927                                                       FFM00000000002162127                               


108768840                                                       FFM00000000001360865T                              


108768840                                                       FFM00000000001796191T                              


108774203                                                       FFM00000000001821871T                              


108774203                                                       FFM00000000001946211T                              


108774203                                                       FFM00000000001914770T
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `HashMap` if you plan to have a key/value design:

```
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

Then instead of using `readLine()` use `read()`.  You want to read a character at a time to be as efficient as possible.  If you read a line at a time, then you have to parse the line String which is a waste of time.  You want two separate inner loops to skip the spaces and look for the value.  The outer loop will look for the key.

Also, use `StringBuffer` instead of `String`.  This is good for when you plan to concatenate lots of Strings or characters.

This pseudo code assumes your file is correct (no missing keys or values).

```
StringBuffer key, value;
char c;
while ((c= in.read()) != null) {
    key = new StringBuffer();    

    if(c != " "){
        key.append(c);
    }else{
        value = new StringBuffer();
        while ((c= in.read()) == " ");//skip all the spaces
        value.append(c);//add last char found

        //find rest of value until new line
        //may want to use  System.getProperty("line.separator") or whatever the char value of new line is.
        while ((c= in.read()) != null && c != "\n") {
            value.append(c);//add last char found
        }

        map.put(key.toString(), value.toString());//map it all together
    }
}
```

**NOTE**:  Treat this as pseudo code.  I haven't tested it myself, but this should be a good way to do it.

Comment: Thank you. From what I could see here at work it looks like it will work. I will try this two night and see how it performs. Thank you again for your help.